# rails _5.0.1_ new toy_app installs 5.1.1 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new in Ruby in Rails, I was trying to follow https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app and learn a bit. I tried `rails _5.0.1_ new toy_app` command but all the time I was getting 5.1.1 version and I had some compatibility problems because of that.

Comment: I solved problem, I run `gem install rails -v 5.0.2` `rails _5.0.2_ new toy_app`. It does install 5.0.3 version of rails which should be fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I wrote in comment, the solution for that was to install `gem install rails -v 5.0.2` and then start project `rails _5.0.2_ new toy_app`, still weird cause that installed me 5.0.3 version, but it works fine now, I solved all compatibility issues.